# automatically assign class type in matlab

Tags: class, matlab

I'd like to obtain a class type of a variable and use it as a function in Matlab.

For example, say `x` is of class  `uint8`. I can obtain this info by `classtype=class(x)`.

What I'd like is to use it on a different variable automatically, such as:

```
y=classstype(y)
```

where `y` is of type `logical` for example.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to cast the value of `y` to a different class.  To this end, you could try using Matlab's `cast()` function.

In your specific instance, you could try:

```
y = cast(y, class(x))
```

This should get the class of variable `x` and cast variable `y` to that class.

Answer (score 0):

The function `class()` returns the string with a class name. You can use it further using the function `eval()` which deals with strings as an input.